# Subtract Six Months From Date

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, vbscript, module

I have a calendar and when I click on a date I have a popup that uses a query that uses a between criteria. This criteria I need to find the exact date 6 months prior to the one I clicked on which is [AbsenceDate]. Im not sure if the way below is the correct way to go because when I go on line [HERE](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?m1=2&d1=11&y1=2013&type=add&ay=&am=3&ad=&aw=) it gives me a few day different results than what access would so I don't know what would be correct. Is there a module I could use that would be better or is this good? Thanks...

```
Between DateAdd("d",-180,Date()) And [Forms]![frm_CalendarInputBox]![subFormCalendarInputBox].[Form]![AbsenceDate]
```

Comment: Worth pointing out, you may get different results with your current approach since you are subtracting 180 days. Not all months have 30 days in them, so this could be why you get different results using a calculator.

Comment: I tried the "m" -6 first and I figured it was just picking the 6th month and not actually calculating 6 months form the actual date to date, well it was but the date on the other end is it 180 days out?

Comment: So, here is a counter question. If today's date is 26th July and you want to backdate it by "1-Month", what should be your expected result? 26th June or 25th June or 27th June? Dateadd("m", -1, Date()) is only going to subtract 1 from the current month and will give 26th June as the output.

Comment: Ok I got it, the "m" -6 does in fact give me the correct date I just had my Date() and formula backwards... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateAdd`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) can subtract months too, with `Interval:="m"`:

```vb
Debug.Print DateAdd("m", -6, Date())
```

And in your query:

```
Between DateAdd("m",-6,[Forms]![frm_CalendarInputBox]![subFormCalendarInputBox].[Form]![AbsenceDate]) And Date()
```